# process functions and variables from derived class of abstract

Tags: c#, xna, abstract, typeof, derived

How do i circumvent questioning from any derived class and writing the code twice?

I have tried the following:

```
Type t = GetType(obj); 
(obj as t).health
```

By doing this, Visual Sudio saysme `health is not member of... blah`

Here's my code:

```
// gameobjects-class    
abstract gameobject
{
Vector2 Position
void update()
etc...


class meteor : gameobject
{
float rotation
etc...

class player : gameobject
{
int health, attackpower
etc...

class enemy: gameobject
{
int health, attackpower
etc...
```

External class accessing data from `GameObject`

```
class anyclass
{
void checkhealth(gameobject obj)   // QUESTION:
{
if (obj as player).health = 0      // 
     kill(obj)                     // 
if (obj as enemy).health = 0       // 
     kill(obj)                     //
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an interface for living objects and then pass that to the method

```
interface ILivingGameObject
{
    int Health {get;set;}
}

class Player : GameObject, ILivingGameObject
{
}

void CheckHealth(ILivingGameObject obj)
{
     if(obj.Health == 0)
          kill(obj);
}
```

You can read more on Interfaces [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173156.aspx)

---

Alternatively you can create a `LivingObject` class that both player and enemy inherit from and pass this to the method

```
class LivingObject : GameObject
{
    int Health {get;set;}
}

class Player : LivingObject
{
}

void CheckHealth(LivingObject obj)
{
}
```